# Installed dbt and was working fine, but getting db cmdlet, function error

Tags: runtime-error, dbt

Issue: Installed dbt and created a project, defined models and ran some tests. Getting this error now while executing dbt.

> dbt : The term 'dbt' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a  path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:1

- dbt run -m eve-source
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dbt:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

System and IDE: Windows 10 and VSCode
Python version: 3.7.3

dbt works fine from the Powershell prompt, but I want it to work with VSCode as well. Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `dbt` and `vscode` workflow, I use the following installation:

---

Application:

- VS Code v1.49.0

Extensions:

- [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)
- [vscode-dbt](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bastienboutonnet.vscode-dbt)

Project Dir:

```
  project_dbt
      | .vscode
      |  > dbt.code-workspace
      |  > settings.json
      | analysis
      | macros
      | models
      | seed
      | tests
      | .gitignore
      | dbt_project.yml
      | packages.yml
      | Readme.md
```

Where `dbt.code-workspace` contents are:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": ".."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

And `settings.json` contents are:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\tools\\miniconda3\\envs\\dbt\\python.exe"
}
```

And then launch python directly to environment via Command Palette Python Ext:
[image]

Just adjust your pythonPath to your `.venv`, `conda env`, or preferred `env` manager.